# Amazon S3 PHP Stream Wrapper Set Public View Permissions for Image

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon PHP SDK for S3 to save images to a bucket.  I need to make sure that every image that gets added is publicly viewable, but I don't want to add list accessibility.  I couldn't find a way to set this at the bucket level so that it propagated to all the uploaded images.

So, my question is, how do I set the permissions on the image after I move it to S3 so that it can be viewed in a browser?

My code looks like this:

```
require_once("aws/aws-autoloader.php");

// Amazon S3
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Create an Amazon S3 client object
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => $amazonKey,
    'secret' => $amazonSecret
));

// Register the stream wrapper from a client object
$s3Client->registerStreamWrapper();

// Save Thumbnail
$s3Path = "s3://".$amazonBucket."/".$folderYear."/".$folderMonth."/";
$s3Stream = fopen($s3Path . $thumbnail, 'w');
fwrite($s3Stream,$thumb_content);
@fclose($s3Stream);
```

I just need help after the image has been saved, how can I make sure the image is publicly viewable but the bucket and folders do not list all the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this at the bucket level using bucket policies. Check out:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html